# Breaking line when text is overflow containing it div

Tags: html

I have code like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>This my text but it is too long and it is stick out from div becaue it has too many characters. And i want it text to break somewhere, beste break it in place where is blank character.</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

I would like to have something looks like this done automatically:

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>This my text but it is too long and it is stick out from div 
                becaue it has too many characters. And i want it text to break
                somewhere, beste break it in place where is blank character.
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>
```

Can i do this in html and css or i need something else, maybe javascript? If i can do this anyhow, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give width to your li in your css file:

```
li
{
        width:150px;
}
```

or like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li style="width:150px;">This my text but it is too long and it is stick out from div becaue it has too many characters. And i want it text to break somewhere, beste break it in place where is blank character.</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/qqzaK/1/

Comment: you can make your own line brakes with '<br />' at the place you wish to break the line

Comment: I know but it is no so easy if i making nested lists containing nested list and so max 63 times.

Comment: It is more complex problem in my app because content of list is a users thing. But thanks at all for this my question.